# Inheriting from template<typename T, T max, T min> struct with multiple template arguments of typename

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, inheritance

this is my first question on this platform after using it as a grateful visitor for years. Please be gentle with me.

I am currently implementing an interface for ADCs that can be used with different types of microcontrollers and different architectures.

Sadly, this limits the usable c++ version to 11 to guarantee compatibility between the MCUs.

The idea was to define a general API ADC struct, in which a typename of a fixed width integer type is passed, together with the maximum achievable Min and Max values of a the ADC. These two values are intended to be stored as a constexpr.

Therefore I came up with this:

```cpp
template<typename T, T max, T min>
struct ADC
{
public:
    static constexpr T maximum = max;
    static constexpr T minimum = min;
    virtual void reset() = 0;
    // ...
};

template<typename T, T max, T min>
struct xyzAdc : ADC<typename T, T max, T min>
{
public:
    uint8_t someSpecificADCStuff = 0xac; // arbitrarily chosen
    // ....
};
```

For example, there might be an ADC which provides a 12 bit resolution. This could be used in single ended or differential mode resulting in a usage something like this:

```cpp
xyzADC<uint16_t, 0, 4095> singleEndedADC;
// or 
xyzADC<int16_t, -2048, 2047> diffADC;
```

Unfortunately, this does not compile. The resulting error message is

```
error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 3)
struct xyzAdc : ADC<typename T, T max, T min>
```

To be honest, I could not find out, to what this error message is hinting.
I did some research but was not able to find a similar question, in which this is covered.

What am I doing wrong? Does c++11 provide another way to achieve what I am trying to do?
Is this in general a reasonable pattern / idea to go with? 
Or should I write another template, which wraps these parameters?

Any help or hints for sources including deeper reading would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
fixed integer type sizes in code, typo not related to question

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  You don't repeat the `typemane` and `T` in `struct xyzAdc : ADC<typename T, T max, T min>`.  You just need `ADC<T, max, min>` since that is the `ADC` you want.

Comment: This fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe

```
template<typename T, T max, T min>
struct xyzAdc : ADC<T, max, min> // no "<typename T, T max, T min>"
{ // ...............^..^^^..^^^
public:
    uint8_t someSpecificADCStuff = 0xac; // arbitrarily chosen
    // ....
};
```

?

Anyway, `4095` is too much for a `std::uint8_t`

```
xyzADC<uint8_t, 0, 4095> singleEndedADC;
```

Comment: This fixed the problem, thank you very much. I Fixed the width of integer type in original code, as it is unrelated to problem.